# How do I authenticate to AD from Go as the currently logged in Windows user?

Tags: windows, go, active-directory, ldap

How do I authenticate to AD from Go as the currently logged in Windows user? Windows commands like 'dsget' do it, how do I replicate that from Go? I'm fully aware of using LDAP to connect to AD but I don't want to ask for a password or store one to bind to AD. I want to bind implicitly like Windows commands do.

Comment: I guess you can use the Windows API (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/wmisdk/accessing-active-directory). I have a wrapper library at `https://github.com/gonutz/w32/tree/master/v2` where you can create PRs or issues to add the functions that you need.